# Viewer for DNxHR HQX files

Tags: windows, avid, dnxhr, video-player

I'm using Avid DNxHR HQX as an intermediate codec to go from Resolve to Premiere, but I can't find a viewer that will play it.

MPC-HC, MPC-BE, MPDN, Windows Media Player even the dreaded quicktime player all refuse to play it. The only thing that works is ffplay.

Anyone know of a player that can handle this codec yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Potplayer](https://www.videohelp.com/software/PotPlayer) plays the HQX HR file I generated using ffmpeg. You have to tell Potplayer to use ffmpeg's MP4/QT demuxer by setting `Preferences -> Filter Control -> Source/Splitter -> MP4/QT` to `FFmpeg MP4 Source/Splitter`.

Comment: Or use mpv player from https://mpv.io

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm using mpv now, looks pretty good!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to the White Paper on the codec.

[AVID DNxHR CODECS](http://www.avid.com/products/avid-dnxhr-and-dnxhd)

You can download the codecs for Quicktime here:

http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/download/Avid-QuickTime-Codecs-LE

Comment: I have the codecs installed, but I still can't play back DNxHR, only DNxHD. Maybe there's something going wrong.

Comment: Same -- after installing the codec, I was still unable to play the video, at least not with Windows media player